# How to mock controllers / rest endpoints for unit testing in Play Framework 2.x [Java]

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, playframework-2.0, mocking

We are developing a project with Java on Play Framework 2.x and have some rest endpoints. Also we have some test cases for them like as follows:

```
    @Test
    public void testLogout() throws Exception {
        FakeRequest request = new FakeRequest("GET", "/product/api/v1/logout");

        Result result = route(request);

        assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(OK);
        assertThat(contentType(result)).isEqualTo("application/json");
        assertThat(contentAsString(result)).contains("result");
    }
```

On the other hand, we have some methods [like `register()`] which can not test in production database.

What is the correct way to test the methods which affect the prod database? I think mocking but I am not sure that and I don't know how to do. If mocking is a good choice, is there any working example?

Please give me some advice about this issue.

Comment: have you checked out these links? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.4/JavaTest and https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.4/JavaFunctionalTest

Comment: [Pact JVM](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm) seems to enable what you want to do, but maybe you should elaborate your question. It is derived from Pact for Ruby and "Enables consumer driven contract testing, providing a mock service and DSL for the consumer project, and interaction playback and verification for the service provider project."

Comment: @sfat: of course I checked out those links and I have lots of test. I just need mocking..

Comment: @Pact JVM: thanks for advice. I'll check it out.

Comment: What persistence framework do you use? Do you use DI?

Comment: This project is a wrapper API project for an external API project. I don't know which framework(s) are using on other project or using DI.

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct way is not to test against production database.

I divide the tests in 2 groups, unit tests and integration tests. Unit tests are commonly known, and in integration tests I test everything that is outside the application itself (for example, the database) and the conections between them.

I run the unit tests using a mock in memory database when needed and integration tests against a database with same structure as the production one but not the same database.

I hope my approach will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have no choice about testing prod database, this is company's choice (correct way or not..). I just want to know how to mock rest api methods (if possible).